Facebook Login Email Permission Stuck in "Ready for Testing" Despite Completing Data Handling Form
How can I move the email permission from "Ready for Testing" to "Advanced Access" or get it approved for public users? Is there any additional step I might be missing, or is there a way to prompt Facebook to review my permission?
I'm integrating Facebook Login with AWS Cognito in my app and require the email permission. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
In the Facebook Developer Console, I added the email permission.
I completed the data handling form for email permission over a week ago.
The app status is currently Ready for Testing, but I want to make it live for production.
Problem:
Even after completing the required data handling form, the email permission status is still “Ready for Testing.” The Request Advanced Access option is not visible, and I can’t seem to submit the permission for further review. The permission status remains in testing mode and isn’t available for public users.
Attempts to Solve:

I checked the Permissions and Features section in the Facebook
Developer Console, but there's no option to request advanced access.
I reviewed the App Review section, but I don’t see any pending actions
I have added a Privacy Policy and completed all required
fields in Settings > Basic.
I have gone through Data Use Checkup to confirm compliance.

I need the email permission to support user registration and authentication in production. The app is currently disabled for non-developer/tester users because the email permission isn't live.

Can anyone help me on this? already added permission of email converted in to ready to testing. I am unable to resolve it .

My applicatiion is in live mode. I only need email permission for login into my app.
